# How to insert data in excel sheet dynamically using xlsxwriter in python?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to **write some data in a sheet using xlsxwriter but the positioning of data writing in the cell is not correct**.

I have a **list name `q_arr` that contains data in lists** as an example -

```
q_arr = [
[ "", "", "", ""],["yes","","","comp",""],["cateA","comp","mode",""]
]
```

so the list does not have fixed elements also it contains blank values which I need to print.

Now I am printing some other data too before this list

```
row = 1
for index, result in enumerate(docs):
    sheet.write(row, 0, result["date"])
    row= row+1
```

now in the for loop, **I need to write code that can dynamically write q_arr values. Also, I have to make sure that data writing must start from column=36 and row=1 as row=0 is the header.**

I have tried the below code but it is not working as the positioning of the row is not correct it writes everything in 1 row.

```
row = 1
for index, result in enumerate(docs):
    sheet.write(row, 0, result["date"])
    for row_values in q_arr:
        sheet.write(rows, cols, row_values)
        cols += 1
            
    cols = 36
    rows += 1
    row = row + 1
```

Also for reference, I am mentioning that when I tried the below code without `for index, result in enumerate(docs):` loop with dummy data everything worked fine.

```
 for row_values in q_arr:
   for val in row_values:

     sheet.write(rows, col, val)

     col += 1

 col = 36
 rows += 1
```

so, H**ow will I write the list of lists dynamically in xlsxwriter in python**?

Comment: I understand you're asking for a solution for xlsxwriter, but, if you were to store your data within a dictionary and then use pandas.DataFrame to output an excel file ...this task would be significantly easier (in my opinion), and you'd sidestep the issue of having to manually write to each specified line altogether

Comment: I guess you are correct, but I am reading data from MongoDB, also as you can see I have mentioned col=36  because the rest data from col=1 to 35 have inserted using xlsxwriter too.

Comment: The last code example would work since it should. In your other code examples you have 'row' and 'rows' is this supposed to be the same variable referencing the row to write to. What is the variable 'docs'?

Comment: docs have data coming from MongoDB like - `title, date` and other values which I am writing in excel